# I get this error when trying to deploy a contract on VENOM

Tags: venom

after running  npx locklift run -s scripts/2-deploy.ts -n local

i get this error

```
        if ("map" in map) 
                  ^
```

TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'map' in undefined
at Factory.initializeContract (/Users/wikiwoo/Desktop/WEBX/vee/node_modules/locklift/internal/factory/index.js:68:23)
at /Users/wikiwoo/Desktop/WEBX/vee/node_modules/locklift/internal/factory/index.js:154:35
at Array.map ()
at Factory.getContractsArtifacts (/Users/wikiwoo/Desktop/WEBX/vee/node_modules/locklift/internal/factory/index.js:153:53)
at Function.setup (/Users/wikiwoo/Desktop/WEBX/vee/node_modules/locklift/internal/factory/index.js:126:23)
at Function.setup (/Users/wikiwoo/Desktop/WEBX/vee/node_modules/locklift/index.js:209:49)
at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at initLockliftStep (/Users/wikiwoo/Desktop/WEBX/vee/node_modules/locklift/internal/cli/steps/initLocklift.js:8:23)
at Command. (/Users/wikiwoo/Desktop/WEBX/vee/node_modules/locklift/internal/cli/commands/run.js:38:5)